# Cannot copy my binary from first stage of docker build to second

Tags: c++, docker, cmake

I am using multi-stage build but something is not working as expected. The images are custom ones and we are having our own artifactory - so don't worry about the links, they are working.

My simple `Dockerfile` is :

```
####################      BUILD Stage      ####################

FROM <url>/my-docker-image:latest AS build-image
COPY . /workarea
WORKDIR /workarea

## run the integration tests as well.

RUN INTEGRATION_TESTS=1 make docker

RUN pwd
RUN ls -l cmake-build/linux_64_static_make_Debug/src/
RUN ls -l cmake-build/linux_64_static_make_Debug/tests/

####################      RUN Stage      ####################

FROM <url>/my-test-image:latest AS run-tests-image

WORKDIR /workarea

COPY --from=build-image /workarea/cmake-build/linux_64_static_make_Debug/src/mybinary.tsk /workarea/cmake-build/linux_64_static_make_Debug/src/
COPY --from=build-image /workarea/cmake-build/linux_64_static_make_Debug/tests/unit/mybinary.t.tsk /workarea/cmake-build/linux_64_static_make_Debug/tests/unit/
COPY --from=build-image /opt/bb/etc/entrypoint.d/99-mybinary.sh /opt/bb/etc/entrypoint.d/99-mybinary.sh
```

Expectation from first stage is to build the .tsk files, using the `make docker` commands which is a wrapper on top of standard cmake commands.

I've added the RUN commands in between, to see if the .tsk files have been created.

```
#12 [build-image 5/7] RUN pwd
#12 sha256:4f0ad0e7daee557776d6c7dfa2faf48dead48ae75ff699a0898879f85255dd30
#12 0.534 /workarea
#12 DONE 0.7s

#13 [build-image 6/7] RUN ls -l cmake-build/linux_64_static_make_Debug/src/
#13 sha256:7989faeb2d337c955e167e5807eb6c6a980e98ab210bbb428b180fc2838686f0
#13 0.617 total 378068
.....
#13 0.617 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 290465864 Oct 15 12:04 mybinary.tsk
#13 DONE 0.7s
```

And the timestamp is the correct one. Nothing complaints when the `COPY` gets run.

Then I run

`docke-compose run my-test`

and run the same `ls -l` there is nothing in there. So, even though the COPY command was ran, I can't see the files.

My `docker-compose.yaml' is :

```
my-test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: test.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/workarea
    environment:
      - INTEGRATION_TESTS=1
```

Any idea what I am missing? I think there is something going wrong with the volumes.

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea what I am missing? I think there is something going wrong with the volumes.

Exactly. If you delete that `bind mount`, I mean `- .:/workarea`, you will surely make it work.

The `mybinary.tsk` already in the container's folder `/workarea`, but you mount current working directory `.` on host to `workarea` of container. Then, the contents in host will override the contents in container.